# How to scan only specific folders in Spring loaded?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-loaded

I would like to configure spring-loaded in Eclipse JUNO. I have downloaded the **spring-loaded.jar** and put it in the eclipse directory where the **eclipse.exe** is located.

I have opened the jetty `build.xml` file and added the following to the target.

```
<jvmarg value="-javaagent:D:/eclipse/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

Now, the spring-loaded is scanning even the pre-defined libraries (the jar files which are included in my project) which I don't want to, since I don't make any changes to them. So, I need to pass it an argument to scan only custom folders of my project. How could I do that?

I am getting the following error, when I simply include the above line.

```
[artifact:mvn] constituent[0]: file:/D:/maven/lib/aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar
[artifact:mvn] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/aether/util/repository/DefaultProxySelector, method: getProxy signature: (Lorg/eclipse/aether/repository/RemoteRepository;)Lorg/eclipse/aether/repository/Proxy;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

Answer (score -1):

add " -noverify" option at the end of the value (some add " -Dverify:none")